# Cannot forward ports when running Linux container on Windows10 as a host

Tags: windows, docker, windows-10, google-cloud-sdk, linux-containers

I'm new using Docker. I have been trying to deploy a Linux container (with Windows as a host) with a Google Cloud image inside using Docker. I'm able to do everything well, at the end the server is running perfectly, but when I want to check the server, using the localhost in the browser, I got a blank page with:

[Blank page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIUHr.jpg)

#### This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM google/cloud-sdk
ENV PATH /usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin:$PATH
WORKDIR docker_folder
COPY local_folder/ .
RUN pwd
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java_dev_appserver.sh", "."]
```

#### This is the command I'm using to build my image (in the CMD):

```
docker build --tag serverdeploy .
```

#### This is the command I'm using to run my container

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 serverdeploy
```

#### This is the stack trace that I got when I run the server

[where I know that I running the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vUvb.jpg)

I did some research and looks like Docker had a problem with the ports when you use a Linux container in Windows (Not sure if it's already solved or not). I've already tried all the possible solutions that I found out there (even trying to replace 'localhost' by all the *ip's* that I get when I run *ipconfig* on the cmd) but I still get the same error.

And, as last hope, I need your help to understand what I'm doing wrong, or if I missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running your service bind to `localhost` - that means **no remote connections** are accepted (as well as binding to `127.0.0.1`. And for your container the host is a remote connection.

Change binding to `0.0.0.0` (which I guess is default) and enjoy.

Btw sharing your `java_dev_appserver.sh` would be helpful for answering the question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have just written docker run -p 0.0.0.0:8080:8080 serverdeploy and I get the same error. Is the correct place to write the binding? And regarding the java_dev_appserver.sh is the Google Cloud SDK

Comment: Its not what I meant. When you bind `-p 0.0.0.0:blahblah` you bind docker to host's interface. While I think your problem is that your service is bind to `localhost` inside container

Comment: So you mean my server should run on 0.0.0.0:8080 instead of localhost:8080? If not, can you tell me what should I change? 

I don't know if I'm misunderstanding something as I'm new at Docker. Thank you for your help

Comment: I manage to make it work! I the CMD line of my Dockerfile to this:
 `CMD java_dev_appserver.sh -a 0.0.0.0 -p 8080 .`

Comment: Congrats! That's what I was talking about when telling about sharing your shell file